# White-Space and Characters after white-space are not getting passed in GET request

Tags: django

Suppose I have a django model like this:

```
class myModel(models.Model):
    names = models.Charfield(max_length=200)
```

Values of objects stored in this model are 'Amanda','John Nash', 'Richard Benson' and 'Joe Williams'

Now i have a html form which has a select element.I am fetching values to be put in option element from myModel using ajax function.Form is something like this:

```
<form>
  <select multiple name='MyNames'>
    <option value='Amanda'>Amanda</option>
    <option value='John Nash'>John Nash</option>
    <option value='Richard Benson'>Richard Benson</option>
    <option value='Joe Williams'>Joe Williams</option>
  </select>
  <input type='submit' name='Save'>
</form>
```

If i select 'Amanda','John Nash' and 'Richard Benson' and click on 'Save' following is the GET request i am getting on my server.

```
HTTP GET /testPage/?MyNames=Amanda&MyNames=John&MyNames=Richard&Save=Submit
```

It is clear from the GET request that white-space and characters after white-space are not being picked up if values are fetched from the server. What could be the possible reason and possible solution for this.

If i donot fetch values of options from server and rather put the values in option element manually, then this is not happening. Request in that case is like this.

```
HTTP GET /testPage/?MyNames=Amanda&MyNames=John+Nash&MyNames=Richard+Benson&Save=Submit
```

**P.S:This is only a sample code.I have not given actual code for the sake of clarity as actual code is quite lengthy.Thanks in advance**

**Actual Ajax Function**

```
$.ajax({
          url:"other",
          type:"GET",
          data: {key:"items"},
          dataType:"json",
          success: function(response)
          {
            if(response.data)
                {
                  var secondDropdown = $(".selB_1"); // select 2nd dropdown
                   secondDropdown.empty();                // empty dropdown
                   secondDropdown.append(
                        "<option " + "disabled selected value" + ">" +"Select corressponding value for key" + "</option>");
                        for (var item of response.data) {      // loop response & create options
                        console.log(item)
                        secondDropdown.append(
                            "<option value=" + item +">" + item + "</option>"

                        );
                    }
                  }
                }
              });
```

**Actual Django View:**

```
class MyChoices(View):
    def get(self,request,*args,**kwargs):
        key = request.GET.get('key')
        if key is None:
            return HttpResponse(json.dumps({
                "error": "Field 'key' is required."
            }), content_type='application/json')

        elif key == 'items':
            data = []
            key_qs = ItemsSearched.objects.all().values(key)


            for item in key_qs:
                if item[key] not in data:
                    data.append(item[key])

            return HttpResponse(json.dumps({"data": data}), content_type="application/json")
```

Comment: Almost certainly, your generated HTML is *not* as you claim, but in fact eg `<option value=John Nash>` without the quotes. You need to show at least the part of the Ajax code that creates the options.

Comment: I have updated the details sir. @DanielRoseman

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I noted in the comment, you're not enclosing the value in quotes in the generated HTML. Change it to add single quotes either side:

```
secondDropdown.append(
    "<option value='" + item +"'>" + item + "</option>"
);
```